# Word generation in Cplex

Tags: cplex, opl

I am pretty new to CPlex and constrait programming and I can't seem to figure out how to solve this problem.
Given a target *k* and a word length *n*, find a set of *k* DNA words of length *n*. A DNA word is a string over the alphabet *{A,C,G,T}* that satisfies those constraints:

- For all pairs of words w1, w2 in the set, the Hamming Distance
  between them must be greater than a given value, d
- At least 50% of the letters in the word must be G or C
- For all pairs of words w1, w2 in the set, the Hamming distance
  between w1 and the Watson-Crick complement of w2 must be greater than
  a given value, d

  The Watson-Crick complement of a word w is obtained by reversing w and replacing all "A" letters by "T" and vice versa, and all "C" letters with "G" and vice versa.

I tried following the Vellino example but I can't seem to think of a way to model the maximization objective. 
Can you please help me start this little project? I am especially interesed in the code outside the "subject to" block.

Thank you!

Comment: So you did not try anything yet? Then i'm afraid it's too broad. It looks relatively straightforward (but it won't be a tiny model) to formulate as MIP though. It's hard to say, which basic building blocks of MIP formulation you are familiar with or not. What do you expect for maximization? Your description has nothing to optimize.. It's a feasibility problem only. So you can set the objective to any constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could start with

```
using CP;

int n=5;
range letters=1..n;
int k=5; // words
range words=1..k;
int d=3;

dvar int x[words][letters] in 0..3; // ACGT

subject to
{
forall(ordered i,j in words) d<=sum(k in letters) (x[i][k]!=x[j][k]);

forall(i in words) 
    count(all(j in letters)x[i][j],1)+
    count(all(j in letters)x[i][j],2)>=n/2;

forall(ordered i,j in words) d<=sum(k in letters) (x[i][k]!=(3-x[j][k]));
}

execute
{

function letterDisplay(n)
{
if (n==0) return "A";
if (n==1) return "C";
if (n==2) return "G";
if (n==3) return "T";
fail();

}


for(var w in words)
{
for(l in letters) write(letterDisplay(x[w][l]));
writeln();
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought I had to find some sort of maximization function, but I understand your code and will use it as a starting point.